# Insert a line-break every n characters, reset n on line-break using Python

Tags: python, regex, string, count, line-breaks

I get a block of text from the Jira REST-Api. I need to insert a line break every 150 characters.

If the 150th character is not a whitespace insert the line break into the last whitespace, that count should reset if that text contains a line break.

i've tried it with regex, but it deletes/ignores the line breaks already in the text and it inserts line breaks in the middle of words

```py
featureText = re.sub("(.{150})", "\\1\n", featureText, 0, re.DOTALL)
#featureText contains some text from the api get request
```

for simplicity's sake let's say i want to add a linebreak every 10 characters. and i have the text

```
My Television is broken
and that sucks
```

i currently get

```
My Televis
ion is bro
ken and th
at sucks
```

what i want is

```
My
Television
is broken
and that
sucks
```

Edit: Clarified my question for it to be loser to the real world.
Only the example uses 10 characters, my real problem uses 150 characters so don't worry about cutting a word in half, i guess there won't be any word that is 150 characters long.

Comment: Don't use Regex. Simply code it with a loop and a condition.

Comment: You're right. I overcomplicated this issue, thanks.

Comment: I've clarified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use textwrap like this:

```
import textwrap

example = textwrap.dedent("""\
    My Television is broken
    and that sucks""")

print '\n'.join(l for line in example.splitlines() 
                  for l in textwrap.wrap(line, width=10))
```

This results in:

```
My
Television
is broken
and that
sucks
```

A better example is:

```
example = textwrap.dedent("""\
    My Television is
    and that sucks""")
```

Which results in:

```
My
Television
is
and that
sucks
```

This better shows that the original lines are individually wrapped.

Comment: that's exactly what i needed! Thanks for helping a python beginner out!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
def split_text(text, n):
    for line in text.splitlines():
        while len(line) > n:
           x, line = line[:n], line[n:]
           yield x
        yield line

text = "abcdefghijklmnopqr\nstuvwxyz"

for line in split_text(text, 10):
    print(line)
```

prints:

```
abcdefghij
klmnopqr
stuvwxyz
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine but I saw a new problem: it cuts words in half.
I will try to improve upon your idea to only insert a linebreak in a whitespace.

Comment: I've clarified my question.

Comment: Ah then I think you just want `textwrap.fill` as @DanD suggests

Comment: Exact :) Sorry for wording my question poorly at first. Thanks for your help tho!